# How to automate clicking in modal?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation

Inside a modal I need to

1. click text "Show hidden fields" so additional fields are available
2. scroll down find field "Billable hours" and update text to 0h
3. then scroll down and click "Update" button

[image]

The modal is part of Tempo timesheet plugin for Jira. So the modal is embedded.

I tried iMarcors but it did not record anything. Would you have any suggestions how to accomplish the task in browser only?

Comment: Can you give us a copy of your code? Do you get any error messages when running your code? If so, what are they?

Comment: iMacro record did not record anything. Then I tried Automa. I got bit better result but still not being able to accomplish what I want.